# Calculate $\text{Var} [-3Z ] $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

- $X$ : Poisson with parameter $1$
- $Y$ : Bernoulli with parameter $\frac{1}{3}$
- $Z=X+Y$

Calculate $\text{Var}[-3Z]$.

I consider that $\text{Var}[aZ]=a^2 \text{Var}[Z]$

$\text{Var}[-3Z]=9 \text{Var}[X+Y]=9 \text{Var}[X]+9 \text{Var}[Y]$ 
 
$\text{Var}[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=2-1=1$ 
 
$\text{Var}[Y]=E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{2}{9}$ 
 
$\text{Var}[-3Z]=9+2=11$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen  Thanks